# MySQL 5.6.13 not executing create table properly

Tags: mysql, sql, nitrousio

I have the following SQL to create a table on a MySQL 5.6.13 instance:

```
CREATE TABLE 'exchange' ( 
'id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
'abbrev' varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
'name' varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
'city' varchar(255) NULL, 
'country' varchar(255) NULL, 
'currency' varchar(128) NULL, 
'time_zone_offset' time NULL, 
'created_date' datetime NOT NULL, 
'last_updated_date' datetime NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY ('id') 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

However, I keep getting the following unhelpful error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''exchange' ( 'id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
'abbrev' varchar(32) NOT NULL, 'n' at line 1
```

I must be missing something glaringly obvious...

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are using single quotes instead of back ticks or no quotes at all.  I'm voting to close as a simple typographical problem.

Comment: The problem with closing this one down however is the above code has come from a beginner's tutorial with no other reference to the problem on S/O. If we leave it here then at least it will flag up in similar searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
CREATE TABLE exchange (
```

Ref:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Excellent, it was the apostrophes causing the trouble throughout the code. I'll mark your answer as correct when the timer counts down :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all quotes, this helped me on a windows machine command line